# PhpStorm changing a specific reformat code option

Tags: phpstorm, docblocks

```php
$new_class = new NewClass; /** @var NewClass $new_class */
```

When I use PhpStorm's code format the above code becomes:

```php
$new_class = new NewClass;
/** @var NewClass $new_class */
```

Is there anyway to make it keep these `@var` comments on the same line where it was?

Comment: I hope thats impossible. BTW PHPStorm knows about the Type of this variable without this block, too.

Comment: 1) You do not need such comment for a such a simple case. 2) In any case; such comments should go BEFORE the declaration (so the comment ill be on the previous line, above the variable).